# Disabling Direct Share for send email Intent with recipient

Tags: android, android-intent

In the app that I work on, there is a button to connect with our support team. This button starts an intent to send an email to a specific email address, like so:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, 
        Uri.fromParts("mailto","support@ourwebsite.com", null));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send support mail"));
```

However, there can be apps who listen to this event, that give Direct Share suggestions (as seen in the screenshot below - suggested names blacked out). Now, I do not want the user to choose the target of the email, they instead should start writing a mail directly to the email I provide in the intent.

Is there a way to disable Direct Share suggestions for this intent, programmatically?

[image: Direct Share suggestions]

Comment: That feels like a bug in the email app -- `ACTION_SENDTO` with a `mailto:` `Uri` should not trigger Direct Share options with different destination addresses. That being said, I do not know of any way for you to block Direct Share for an `Intent`.

Comment: In the meantime, I have created and starred and issue in the bug tracker. Feel free to star it too: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111229747

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, 
        Uri.fromParts("mailto","support@ourwebsite.com", null));
emailIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: While this does eliminate the problem with Direct Share, it also forces the user to use the Gmail app. As I would like to give a choice between mailing apps, this is not an ideal solution, unfortunately.